Spring security doesn't work with tomcat 10
I write a mini application to try the implementation of a security spring application. It works with a Tomcat 9 server and displays a login page. When I deploy the application on Tomcat 10, the login page doesn't appears.
Can you help me ?
The components of the application are the following :
A web.xml :
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>

A pom.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sharex30</groupId>
  <artifactId>SSA</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>MavenBootstrap Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- PARAMETRAGE SERVLET -->
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
        

        
    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
 

    <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- SECURITY -->
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>   
  

  <build>
    <finalName>MavenBootstrap</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>

Two java classes :
a SecurityConfig.java
package com.sharex30.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}

a SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java
package com.sharex30.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
      extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}

a web page :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css"  href="resources/styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="d1">MavenBootstrap</div>
        <div class="d2">Test sécurité</div>
        <div>Version : 2024-06-08_18:55</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

Thanks

Comment by zawarudo: There was a breaking point between Spring 5 and Spring 6 when they renamed packages from javax to jakarta. Long story short mixing those two packages do not work together. Things that work together is Spring 5 + Tomcat 9 because they both use javax packages, and Spring 6 and Tomcat 10 work together because they use jakarta packages. If you want your application to run on Tomcat 10, you need to use Spring 6 and migrate all javax dependencies to jakarta dependencies. ...

...Also, useful information minimal JDK for new Spring and Tomcat is JDK17.

Thanks. I configure the application with Spring 5 and Tomcat 9 and JDK 17. It works fine.
